# Process for upgrading MySQL Master-Slave to a new release series version

Tags: mysql-5.7, upgrade, patching, process

I have several MySQL servers that I want to upgrade from 5.7.31 to the most recent release series (5.7.36 I believe), but in one test I found that replication on one server set failed, and it required me to re-import a backup from the primary to recover.

I don't see any official documentation from MySQL on how to do this properly. Is there anyone who has done this before with Master-Slave replication, and if so, what steps did you take to make sure you didn't break replication?

Comment: What exact steps were performed for upgrade? Was `mysql_upgrade` script launched? Do you have full or partial replication? Is it statement- or row-based, or mixed?

Comment: This was done through a patching tool, which per the logs ran `/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confdef install mysql-server-5.7=5.7.36-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`. I don't see anything in the logs that the tool ran a `mysql_upgrade` after this command. 

And this is running full row-based replication.